# How to Add dot in string

Tags: c#, linq

I just want to run all these queries as a single query.

```
string[] arrs = new string[] { ".sds", ".pps", "tbt", "dd." };

string[] val= (from string i in arrs
               where !i.StartsWith(".")
               select "."+i).ToArray();

string[] val1 = (from i in arrs
                 where i.StartsWith(".")
                 select i).ToArray();

var p = val1.Union(val);//get value in single array.e
```

Comment: Btw, don't use `Union` if you know that there are no duplicates or you don`t want to prevent duplicates, use `Concat` instead which doesn't change the sequences and is more efficient.

Answer (score 6):

```
var p = (from s in arrs
         select s.StartsWith(".") ? s : "." + s).ToArray();
```

or non-query syntax:

```
var p = arrs.Select(s => s.StartsWith(".") ? s : "." + s)
            .ToArray();
```

and you might want to add `.Distinct()` if you don't want duplicates as in the case with `{ "foo", ".foo" }`.

```
var p = arrs.Select(s => s.StartsWith(".") ? s : "." + s)
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
var pp = arrs.Select(x => x.StartsWith(".") ? x : "." + x);
```